# update database when I change in dataGridView

Tags: vb.net

I m new in VB. I want to update my database when I make any change in dataGridView. Can anyone give me details about this?
the scenario is I will change value from datagridview and after I click update button I should change the database value.code is

Private Sub btnModify_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnModify.Click

```
    Dim cmdbuilder As New Odbc.OdbcCommandBuilder(da)

    ds = gridDisplay(cmbxState.SelectedItem)

    Try
        da.Update(ds.Tables("districtMaster"))

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: is giving error like Error 2 Value of type 'System.Data.DataTable' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.DataSet'.

Comment: my gridDisplay function is

 Function gridDisplay(stateName)

        
        Dim query As String = "select row_number() OVER (ORDER BY d.district_name) AS SrNo, d.district_name as District, s.state_name as State,d.status as Status from sg_state_mst s, sg_district_mst d where s.state_code=d.state_code and s.state_name = '" & stateName & "' order by(district_name)"

        ds = obj.displyQuery(query, "districtMaster")

        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("districtMaster") ' Assigning dataset as source for the dataGridView

        Return ds

    End Function

Comment: Did you tried the code posted in my answer?

Comment: Yes... But Its not working

Answer (score 0):

You must define an `InsertCommand` in your DataAdapter. Then you'll need to call the Update method of the adapter when you want to save the changes.

**Populating the DataGridView on Form Load**

```
Private myConString As String
Private con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
Private Dadapter As OleDbDataAdapter
Private DSet As DataSet

Private Sub Form_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    myConString = "Your connection string here"
    con.ConnectionString = myConString
    con.Open()
    Dadapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * from Table", con)
    DSet = New DataSet
    Dadapter.Fill(DSet, "Table")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = DSet.Tables("Table")
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

**Updating the database**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Using con = new New OleDbConnection(myConString)
    con.Open()
    Dadapter.Update(DSet, "Table")
End Using
End Sub
```

From the Docs:

**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update%28v=VS.100%29.aspx**